# How to mock test python requests

Tags: python, django, mocking, python-requests

I want to know how to write mock python request tests.

```
def request_headers():
    payload = {
        'client_id': settings.STAT_SERVER['CLIENT_ID'],
        'client_secret': settings.STAT_SERVER['CLIENT_SECRET'],
        'username': settings.STAT_SERVER['USERNAME'],
        'password': settings.STAT_SERVER['PASSWORD'],
        'grant_type': 'password',
    }
```

How can I mock test all of this?

```
    token_url = settings.STAT_SERVER['URL'] + 'o/token/'

    r = requests.request(
        method="POST", url=token_url, data=payload, verify=False)

    if r.status_code != 200:
        msg = "Failed to authenticate. Error code {}: {}"
        msg = msg.format(r.status_code, r.text)
        LOGGER.error(msg)
    credentials = r.json()
```

Here's the base_headers

```
    base_headers = {
        'Content-Type': 'application/json',
        'Accept': 'application/json, */*'
    }
    base_headers['Authorization'] = "{} {}".format(
        credentials['token_type'], credentials['access_token']
    )
LOGGER.debug('Get token: credentials={}'.format(credentials))
return base_headers
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

[The unittest.mock.patch decorator](https://docs.python.org/3/library/unittest.mock.html#unittest.mock.patch) is an awesome tool for solving these things.

So you would do something like:

```
from unittest.mock import Mock, patch

@patch("requests.request")
def test_request(request_mock: Mock):
    response_mock = Mock(status_code=200)
    response_mock.json.return_value = {"foo": "bar"}
    request_mock.return_value = response_mock
```

Comment: Could you expound more on this?

Comment: @NoObiE the patch decorator replace all usage of the object passed into it with a Mock object. Meaning anywhere where you use requests, it will instead use the response_mock. If you want to know what a python Mock is, I suggest you read the whole article in the link I posted.